# jQuery: Expected an assignment or function call an instead saw an expression for an ifelse shortstatement?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, checkbox, expression, warnings

In my Komodo IDE i get a warning message

"Expected an assignment or function call an instead saw an expression"

for this line:

```
data.aktiv == '1' ? $('#aktiv').attr('checked', 'checked') : $('#aktiv').attr('checked', false);
```

and for this line

```
 $('#aktiv').isCheck() ?  aktiv = 1 : aktiv = 0;
```

What is here the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's warning you that you're abusing the conditional operator as a replacement for `if`/`else`. To use the conditional operator properly, change it to:

```
$('#aktiv').attr('checked', data.aktiv == '1' ? 'checked' : false);
```

and

```
aktiv = $('#aktiv').isCheck() ? 1 : 0;
```

For the general case, if you can't use a shortcut like the above, and you have code like

```
condition ? statement1 : statement2
```

you can fix the linting error by using

```
if (condition) {
  // statement1
} else {
  // statement2
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's it.